# I have the error, TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'function' and 'int' and I don't know how to fix it

Tags: python, function, integer

def fortLatSeconds(FORTLAT, fortLatDegree, fortLatMinutes):
fortLatSeconds= round(((FORTLAT - fortLatDegree - fortLatMinutes / 60) * 3600), 4)

```
return fortLatSeconds
```

fortLatSeconds= fortLatSeconds(FORTLAT, fortLatDegree, fortLatMinutes)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! When posting a question, please make sure it is a Minimal, Reproducible Example

Answer (score 1):

Variables that are named the same as functions can cause major problems and should be avoided as much as possible.

Comment: I have tried changing the variable names but I still end up with the same error